# Read and Rewrite the same file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I have to read from a file, do some operations based on the data I got from that file and then rewrite the whole file with new values obtained after the operations were made. I tried

```
fstream file("date.in", ios::in|ios::out)
```

but seems like it puts the new set of data at the end of file. Also tried

```
fstream file("date.in", ios::in|ios::out|ios::trunc)
```

but then I can't even read the first set of data as it appears not to be there.

Comment: The much simpler solution is to open the file for reading, read it, close it, and then open it again for writing and write it.

Comment: something like ifstream file("date.in");
...
file.close();
ofstream file("date.in");
....
?

Comment: Yes. Or use them in different scopes (e.g. inside separate functions) so you don't need to manually close anything.

Comment: seems like it works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and write to the same offsets in the file, you can set the put and get pointers with `seekp()` and `seekg()`. Their documentation can be found at [cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com).